# VBA Excel FileDialog to set/reset filters

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a macro that asks a user to choose multiple files for data analysis. User selects a Excel or CSV file first (XLSX, XLS, CSV), then asks for a second file but CSV only. The intent of the tool is to combine the two data files into one.

In one Sub, I ask the user to select any compatible XLSX, XLS, or CSV files using the FileDialog code:

```
Dim myObj As Object
Dim myDirString As String
Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With myObj
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop"
    .Filters.Add "Custom Excel Files", "*.xlsx, *.csv, *.xls"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select Excel file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    myDirString = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

It seems to filter appropriately:

[image: Custom Excel Files]

After this data analysis in complete, then the user runs a second sub to select another file, but it must be a CSV file only. So I use this code to request CSV:

```
Dim yourObj3 As Object
Dim yourDirString3 As String
Set yourObj3 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With yourObj3
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop"
    .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select CSV file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    yourDirString3 = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

The problem is the FileDialog box remembers the first filter (Custom XLS) and they need to click the drop down to see the appropriate filter for CSV only...

[image: Select CSV]

So this would certainly be confusing to the user...I'm guessing I need to "clear" our that first filter after the user completes the first macro. Any suggestions on that code to clear (or reset) the first filter?

Tried adding this below it when I found what I thought was a similar question [FileDialog persists previous filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270091/filedialog-persists-previous-filters):

```
With .Filters
.Clear 
End With
```

But results in Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: Using the `.Clear` method of the `.Filters` property of a `FileDialog` object works, so all I can think is you didn't put the `With .Filters` within your `With yourObj3` block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in my environment. The only thing I made differently was to declare dialogs as `FileDialog` instead of `Object`.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myObj As FileDialog
    Dim myDirString As String
    Set myObj = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With myObj
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Custom Excel Files", "*.xlsx, *.csv, *.xls"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
    End With
    Dim yourObj3 As FileDialog
    Dim yourDirString3 As String
    Set yourObj3 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With yourObj3
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: P.S.  I suspect that the issue is really that the OP put the `With .Filters` outside the other `With` blocks, so VBA didn't know what the `.` in `.Filters` was referring to.  The code works whether it is a `Object` or a `FileDialog`.

Comment: I'm **always** right!!  (Except when my wife says I'm not.)

Comment: Yes! Thank you VBobCat, worked wonderfully. @YowE3K you are correct, i put it under a different With block... doh!

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not directly the answer to the specific `msoFileDialogFilePicker` from the OP (and googled this answer), I had the same problem with the `msoFileDialogSaveAs` dialog in Excel 2010 where errors are raised trying to modify the filters in any way because it [obviously is not supported](https://analystcave.com/vba-application-filedialog-select-file/#crayon-5d3856b610c20541985699) :-/

> The `msoFileDialogSaveAs` dialog does NOT support file filters