# Save Access Report as PDF

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using VBA macro attached to a "Save File" button on a form.  Would like two things:  In the SaveAs dialog box, I would like the default fil name to be "Inspections Due" and the default file type to be PDF.The following code opens the SaveAs dialog, with no default name, and file type is *.*

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
If fd.Show Then

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Inspections Due", acFormatPDF, 
fd.SelectedItems(1), True

End If
```

Revised code below:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With fd
    .InitialFileName = "Inspections Due"
    .Filters.Add "PDF", "*.PDF"
    .FilterIndex = 1
End With

If fd.Show Then
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Inspections Due", acFormatPDF, 
fd.SelectedItems(1), True
End If

End Sub
```

I have tried different values for filter index, including, 1,2,25 and get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332735/vba-excel-filedialog-to-set-reset-filters

Comment: try to remove `.Filters.Add "PDF", "*.PDF"`

Answer (score 1):

> In the SaveAs dialog box, I would like the default fil name to be
>   "Inspections Due"

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
fd.InitialFileName = "Name you need"
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  is there a similar command to force a PDF format?

Comment: @RobertKendall - yes, by using two different way. 2nd way: set index `fd.FilterIndex = 25` (in Excel 2013 it's PDF). 1st way: clear all filters and add own one, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332735/vba-excel-filedialog-to-set-reset-filters

Comment: I tried both methods, got errors both ways.  'Object doesn't support this method' on the .filters.add command line.

Comment: @RobertKendall. `fd.FilterIndex = 25` should works. can you show full source code of your procedure?

Comment: I edited the original post to show changes.  I still get the same error on the fd.filter line